# Why doesn't changing the value of the object that is pointed doesn't change in shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

While using raw pointer if you changed the value of the object that is pointed the pointer's value while dereferecing also changes. But while using shared_ptr that is not the case. Why is it so?

```
    int i = 3; 
    shared_ptr<int> q = make_shared<int>(i);
    //  what i want "int*q = &i;"
    i = 5;
    cout << *q << endl; //isn't it suppose to print 5
```

Comment: `i` is simply copied when the shared pointer is created. It stays unrelated.

Comment: what's the point of using shared_ptr then? we can just use another integer.

Comment: Get the point using two or more shared pointer variables. These would show the behavior you expected.

Comment: @user3466563 If you don't understand the point of shared_ptr then don't use it. Seriously dynamic memory allocation is a big subject, and it only makes sense to learn it when you understand what the purpose is. You have plenty else to be learning in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

`make_shared<int>` is analogous to `new int` not `&`.

Comment: thx for the reply. how can i make sure that it's "&" and not "new int" then? Like int*q = &i;

Comment: @user you should not.  Making a shared pointer to an automatic storage (stack) variable means that the point of a shared pointer (lifetime management) is nullified and/or broken.  An i t on the staxk goes away when the scope ends, no later and no earlier.  The shared ptr cannot claim ownership.

Comment: @user3466563 Are you trying to achieve something specific here or is this just an academic exercise?

Comment: i want to achieve "int*q = &i". I'm practicing for my exams and they have encouraged to use smart pointers.

Comment: @user smart pointers manage lifetimes.  Automatic storage variables (stack variables) also manage lifetimes.  You cannot have two different lifetime management systems in control of one storage location.

Comment: then why would you use shared_ptr then, as it behaves like a new variable. like "int q = i" instead

Comment: Because you want data whose lifetime is controlled as a shared resource.  Lifetime management must be considered when you create things in C++.